# sugarcrm - add scheduler div to existing content when clicked on "schedule meeting" under activities subpanel of leads module

Tags: sugarcrm

In leads detail view under Activities subpanel, when clicked on "schedule meeting" I get some fields to schedule a meeting. I found these fields are coming from

```
mysugar\modules\Meetings\metadata\quickcreatedefs.php
```

But in addition to these fields I need scheduler div to be placed right below these fields so that while scheduling a meeting we can see what all times are occupied. I found that the code to this is in

```
mysugar\modules\Meetings\tpls\footer.tpl
```

How to add the above tpl to quickcreatedefs.php? It contains all arrays.

I am seeing this scheduler div when clicked on "Full Form" button. But that redirects to other page. I just want to put this same scheduler div(graph that shows what all times are occupied) while scheduling quick meeting itself.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view defs in custom/modules/{modulename}/metadata you can define a footer tpl like this:

```
$viewdefs ['Meetings'] = array (
  'QuickCreate' =>
      array (
        'templateMeta' => array (
           'form' => array (
               .
               .
               .
               .
              'footerTpl' => 'modules/Meetings/tpls/footer.tpl',
               .
               .
               .
```

you just have to ensure that the used smarty variables for the footer tpl are set